# can't render :template with validation error when using :id in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have both task and request controllers and models respectively. The new action of request depends on a task :id which is included in the route. If the request cannot be save due to a validation error, I need to be able to render the new action of the request controller with the task :id. However, when the code below runs, I get a template is missing error.

**How can I render the new template with the task :id as a param?**

```
/task/1/request/new


  if !@request.save
     render :template => new_task_request_path(@blog)    # /task/1/request/new
  end
```

-----> Error:  Template is missing - 
Missing template blogs/1/requests/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `new_task_request_path(@blog)` generates a relative URL.
When rendering a template you need to give it the path to the template, not the relative URL.

I can't tell where your view template is going to be without more information, but try changing your code in the `create` action to the following:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
@request = @task.requests.new(params[:request])

if !@request.save
  render 'new'
end
```

You can then access the Task ID using `@task.id` in your view.

This assumes that `Task` has many `Requests`, and that this action is in your `RequestsController`. If you're using a different relationship you'll need to update the controller action code as necessary. Similarly, if it's a different controller you should update the template path to be something like `'requests/new'`.

Comment: I have similar code to what you added and I have access to @task.id. The problem is that rails won't render the 'new' template with the task :id.       render :template => "/tasks/1/requests/new' also results in a missing template error

Comment: Don't render your template with a relative URL. You need to use the file path to the template. If your action is in the `RequestsController`, and you haven't namespaced your controllers, then template render call should be `render :template => "new"`.

Comment: The problem is that I have @task = Task.find(params[:task_id]) in the 'new' action, so the task is loaded from the route param the first time, but not again once validation fails...

Comment: render 'new' turned out to be just fine. Never overthink ;)

Comment: Right, in Rails 3+ you don't need to use `:action => ` or `:template =>` with `render` in an action. But the above code should still work.